# Name for class library that is specific to the full .NET Framework (Desktop)

Tags: c#, .net, mono, naming-conventions, portable-class-library

I have a library that consists of 2 assemblies:

- a Portable Class Library with the common code.
- a Class Library that provides code that is specific to the Desktop .NET Framework.

The PCL has the name "MyLib".
How should I name the platform-specific library?

Some options I have been thinking are:

- MyLib.Deskop
- MyLib.DotNet
- MyLib.Win32
- MyLib.NetFx
- MyLib.FullNetFx

Is there any standard? 
And... what may change if I have another class library that is for Mono?

Comment: There is no standard so far and my project chose Full. Though now I think Desktop is a more suitable option.

Comment: Why have two? You can stick the Desktop specific stuff in the same library and use precompilation directives to remove code if its just for PCL or if it includes the full framework. If its all "common" code but the only distinction is platform, I'd avoid having two libraries, it makes for linking difficult when you have one executable for two platforms.

Comment: I think that conditional compilation heavily increases the mental load when reading the code and has a bad effect in maintainability. I think code should be as readable as possible. Also, the specific library contains full classes, not just spare lines.